# for comprehensions with if guard

Tags: scala, monads, for-comprehension, either

How do I use for comprehensions with if guard?

```
  type Error = String
  type Success = String
  def csrfValidation(session:Session, body:JsValue):Either[Error,Success] = {
    val csrfRet = for (csrfSession <- csrfStateSessionValidation(session).right;
                           csrfReq <- csrfStateReqBodyValidation(body).right if (csrfSession == csrfReq)) yield (csrfReq)
    if (csrfRet.isRight)
      Right(csrfRet)
    else {
      Logger.warn("request and session csrf is not the same")
      Left("Oops,something went wrong, request and session csrf is not the same")
    }
  }
```

I got this error when using it.

```
'withFilter' method does not yet exist on scala.util.Either.RightProjection[Error,Success], using `filter' method instead
```

**EDIT:**
I got another error. I think it returns an option result when if guard is used.

```
[error] type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Option[scala.util.Either[Nothing,controllers.ProfileApiV1.Success]]
[error]  required: scala.util.Either[?,?]
[error]  csrfReq <- csrfStateReqBodyValidation(body).right if (csrfSession == csrfReq)) yield (csrfReq)
```

**EDIT2**

```
This is what I did to fix above error. I also move if-guard to later process.

val result = for {
  foo <- Right[String,String]("teststring").right
  bar <- Right[String,String]("teststring").right
} yield (foo, bar)

result fold (
  ex => Left("Operation failed with " + ex),
  v => v match { 
    case (x,y) =>
        if (x == y) Right(x)
        else Left("value is different")
  } 
)
```

Comment: 2.10. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe what you are seeing is a compiler warning and not an actual error.  The `RightProjection` does not support `withFilter` which is what is "preferred" (but not yet required) for a guard condition, so plain old `filter` is used instead.  As to the difference to these functions and why this came about, check out the link below for an explanation.

http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Rethinking-filter-td2009215.html#a2009218

Comment: Is there a way to suppress this warning? I checked it is harmless where I used it but shows up on every build.

Answer (score 0):

Add either a semi-colon or a new line just before the `if`.